# Changing to using bootstrap via npm

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I am working on a project which currently uses bootstrap.  However this has been done by loading the bootstrap files into a subdirectory.  I'd like move to using npm as this will make it much easier to keep up to date.

Our existing `style` folder includes `bootstrap` and `source` as a subfolders + an `index.js` file:

```
var ms = require('ms');
var join = require('path').join;
var less = require('transform')('less');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

.............*other code*

app.get('/bootstrap.css', less(join(__dirname, 'source',
                                    process.env.COMPANY_ID + '-root.less')));
app.get('/print.css', less(join(__dirname, 'source',
                                process.env.COMPANY_ID + '-print.less')));

module.exports = app;
```

In the source folder we then have a number of `.less` files including a `company-root.less` which imports various less files:

```
@import "./bootstrap/bootstrap.less";    
@import "./variables/all.less";
@import "./variables/company.less";   
@import "./customcss.less";    
@import "./subnav.less";    
@import "./nav-list.less";
```

I have added bootstrap to `package.json` and run `npm install`, so have bootstrap in the `node_modules` folder, but can't get the project to run with the new files.  I have tried putting

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
global.jQuery = $;
require('bootstrap');
```

into `index.js`
This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Dee\Documents\GitHub\MAPS\node_modules\bootstrap\js\transition.js:36:29
```

I have tried changing the first line of `company-root.js` to:

```
@import (npm) "bootstrap";
```

OR

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
```

but this just results in no formatting.

I've spent three hours trawling the net but am making no progress.  Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a library like 
[bootstrap-sass-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/bootstrap-sass-loader)
or
[bootstrap-webpack](https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack).

This works in some cases, but not in all webpack configurations

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error as well. I was working on a small demo that needed bootstrap in the HTML and I was trying to load the bootstrap in the `.js` file using the `require(bootstrap)`.

I removed the `require(bootstrap0` from the `.js` file.

I went to my HTML and just added bootstrap to the `<head>` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My .js file is this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Ran my project and it worked fine. The error went away. I realize this might not be what you were looking for, but I wanted to post my solution in the event someone else is getting that error message.